# Android: Bluetooth socket not connecting

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I have the following code in my connectThread which I am using from youtube tutorials to understand how to make a bluetooth connection. The socket is unable to connect. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I am using a try catch

```
public void run(){
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            Log.i(TAG, "RUN mConnectThread");
            // get a blue tooth socket for a connection with the given bluetoothdevice

            try{
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket " + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);

            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create InsecureRfcommSocket" + e.getMessage());
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket

            try {
                // this is a blocking call  and will only return on a succesful connection or an exception
                System.out.println(mmSocket);
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected");
            }catch (Exception e){
                // close the socket
                try{
                    mmSocket.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, " run: Closed socket");
                }catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "mConnectThread: run: Unable to close connection in socket" + e1.getMessage());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }
```

Comment: With what are you trying to connect the Android device?

Comment: I am trying to connect the android device to the following part: 
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/steval-spbt2atv3-954220.pdf

However I am trying to connect to that device from my android not the other way round.